# Falha de segmentação na função malloc()

Tags: c

Eu estou tendo um erro de falha de segmentação quando eu tendo implemtar um array dinamico de ponteiros para poder armazenar o conteúdo de um arquivo linha-por-linha.

```
size_t file_mem_init(char ***ptr,FILE * file){

   size_t mem_size = getnline(file); // retorna a quantidades de linha no arquivo
   size_t x;

 if(mem_size == 0){
    puts("Arquivo vazio");
    exit(1);
  }
    *ptr = malloc(sizeof(**ptr)*mem_size);
    if(*ptr == NULL){
      perror("malloc in *ptr");
      exit(-1);
    }

    for(x = 0; x < mem_size && !feof(file);x++){
      // DEBUG 
      printf("%zu",x);

      // sizeofline(file) retorna a quantidade de caracteres de uma linha no arquivo. 
      *ptr[x] = malloc(sizeof(***ptr) * sizeofline(file)); <---- Falha de Segmentação
      if(*ptr[x]==NULL){
    printf("Na variavel *ptr[%zu]: %s",x,strerror(errno));
    exit(-1);
      }
      x++;
    }

    return mem_size;
}


void file_mem_free(char ***ptr,size_t len){
  while(len > 0)
    free(*ptr[--len]);

  free(*ptr);

}
```

Comment: Em qual linha esta o erro? Já tentou executar em um depurador?

Comment: Só pra eu entender a idéia, tem como explicar a lógica que você usou para escrever esta linha: `*ptr = malloc(sizeof(**ptr)*mem_size);`?

Comment: Segundo o gdb a falha de segmentação está no malloc(). O sizeofline() retorna no mínimo 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito ser meramente um erro de precedência de operadores. Você aloca memória para a variável `*ptr`. Mas ao utilizar dentro do loop, você usa `*ptr[x]`. Essa expressão é interpretada como `*(ptr[x])`, que tenho certeza não é o que você quer. Use `(*ptr)[x]` para evitar o problema. Parênteses são obrigatórios nesse caso.

Ou melhor ainda: use uma variável auxiliar:

```
char** lines = *ptr = malloc(...);

//...

char* line = lines[x] = malloc(...);
```

Assim não tem erro.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que simplifiques a instrução

```
*ptr[x] = malloc(sizeof(***ptr) * sizeofline(file));
```

Por exemplo para

```
size_t tmp1 = sizeofline(file);
*ptr[x] = malloc(tmp1); // sizeof(***ptr) == 1
```

e agora verifica se o erro é no `malloc()` ou no `sizeofline()`.

Comment: Segundo o gdb a falha de segmentação está no malloc(). O sizeofline() retorna no mínimo 1.

Comment: Hmmm. Antes do `malloc()` experimenta imprimir a quantidade de bytes a alocar: `printf("Tentando alocar %zu bytes.\n", tmp1);`

Comment: alocando 19 no elemento *ptr[0]
alocando 1 no elemento *ptr[1]
alocando 1 no elemento *ptr[2]
alocando 1 no elemento *ptr[3]zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out main.c

Comment: O código atual esta aqui:  https://github.com/tunixbsd/testes-bugados